# sed - get last value in file

Tags: regex, sed

I am making a script to collect a value from an external file. In the middle of this, I saw myself having trouble with the following sed command to limit the result to a single line.

The following command searches for all words with "value=" by collecting the next text, ignoring rows with "#"

```
NUM=$(sed -n -e '/#/!s/^.*value=//p' $LOGFILE)
```

I found other command variations for this but none of them allowed the use of words to be ignored as is the case with this command line.

Any soul to do this capture only the final line but still ignoring lines that contain "#"?

optional: can you adapt this command to capture only numbers, ignoring rest the words on the line?

Comment: While some may be willing to guess, you will likely get much better quality answers if you show some sample input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Here's 3 ways:

1. if you need just sed:

   ```
   sed -n '/value=/h; ${g; s/value=//p}' file
   ```
2. if you can use other tools:

   ```
   tac file | sed -n '/value=/{s///p;q}'
   ```
3. or, this is quite readable:

   ```
   awk -F= '$1 == "value" {value = $2} END {print value}' file
   ```

Comment: "value =" has a number written by another script that adds 1 more each execution of it (another sed command that searches the value and substitutes on the same line). After line with "value="  there may be a similar   terms but with "#" . Ignoring line that have "#", I can keep the script more portable

Comment: You want to
 skip lines that start with "#". Do you know how to match that? Do you know what the sed command is to go to the next line of the input?

Comment: I'm new to it, I only found this command that extracts the result of "value =", ignoring the lines with "#", but it is not limited to the last result: sed -n -e '/#/!s/^.*value=//p' log.file

Comment: You could pipe that command into `tail` to get the last line: `sed -n '/#/!s/^.*value=//p' log.file | tail -1` -- do you understand all of that?